# Why I get there is already an open datareader associated with this connection which must be closed first error?

Tags: c#, mysql

```
try
{
        string log = "SELECT * from rfidprototype.account where username ='" + USERNAME + "' and password = '" + PASS + "';";

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(log, SQLconn);
        MySqlDataReader dRead;

        dRead = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (DRead.Read())
        {
            MenuHere form = new MenuHere();

            form.Show();
            form.ManageTile.Enabled = false;

            SQLconn.Close();
            DRead.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password!");
            DiriLogin form = new DiriLogin();
            form.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cleaned up your code, but you question is still lacking enough information and context. Please add everything that can help us understand your problem.

Comment: Hi, OneCodex, and welcome to SO. In future questions, please correctly format your code before posting, and put the "questioning" part in the body, not the title. 
Also, pointing the line throwing the exception wouldn't hurt :) 
And refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Just swap `SQLconn.Close();` and `DRead.Close();` order. And of course read @Sonner Gonul answer

Comment: @fvu, beat me by 10 seconds :\

Comment: is `DRead.Read()` is same as `dRead.Read()` or it is typo??

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you try to close your connection *while* you read your reader.

Instead of using `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually, use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection, command and reader automatically.

But more important, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

And **do not** store your passwords as a plain text. Read: [Best way to store password in database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1054022/447156)

```
using(var SQLconn = new MySqlConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = SQLconn.CreateCommand())
{
    // Set your CommandText property.
    using(var dRead = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // Do your stuff
    }
}
```

As a last thing, `PASSWORD` is a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) in MySQL. You *might* need to use it as between ` characters depending your database manager is case sensitive or not.